# iPad UIPopoverController does not go over inputView in UITextView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton, uitextview, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to set up a popover to point to a UIButton in a view that is used as a "inputView" to a UITextView.  I can get everything to work and the correct data is going into the UIPopoverController.  But it is exhibiting a behavior that is not what I expected.  So here is what I have.  The following method is written in a UIView subclass that is the inputView of the UITextView and is also the view in which the button resides.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchDown:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    MyPopoverContentController *controller = [[MyPopoverContentController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
    [controller setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSize(320.0, 304.0)];
    self.popupController = [[UIPopupController all] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [self.popupController presentPopoverFromRect:[button frame] inView:self permittedArrowDirectoions:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

Now, I would expect the popover to float over the inputView and the pointer would touch the button I've placed into the view.  But it does not.  In the 'X' origin the popover point is correct.  But it appears the UIView when acting as a input view it won't allow the popover to move down over the inputView to the UIButton.  Am I overlooking something?

Thanks for any help,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I visited this question.  I turned this in to Apple and it is a bug.  They are working on it.

Comment: Did you bug report ever got open/closed/implemented?

Comment: I just checked and it's still open.  I haven't checked lately to see if this is still a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self.popupController presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds inView:button permittedArrowDirectoions:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I tried that.  It moved the popover to the right of the button I tapeed as far as the button was from the left edge.  That is what it should do since the view is supposed to be the root origin by which it measures where to place the popover.