# ios Hiding the Keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

**My Question** is : `What is the best way to implement "Hiding Keyboard while PickerView (which is inside the PopOver) is Visible"?`

**What I Want :**

I have one view which has around `15 TextFields`. Out of 15 , say 7 uses `UIPickerView` ( that resides into `UIPopOverController` ) to implement the `DropDown Functionality`. My Problem is when the KeyBoard is Visible and I Click on the `UITextField` with `UIPickerView`, KeyBoard is not hiding. What is the best way to implement this ?

**What I Tried :**

I tried to implement `inputView` but it is only used for `UIPickerView` while I have `UIPickerView` inside `UIPopOverController`. I think that's why I am unable to use `inputView` property. According to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022195/ipad-uipopovercontroller-does-not-go-over-inputview-in-uitextview), it is Bug from Apple.

**Update** :

Look , I know that using textField Delegates , we can implement this. But I found `inputView` property of `UITextField` and I found it quite interesting as you have to just assign it as :

```
textField.inputView = pickerView;
```

But i have the `UIPickerView` inside `PopOver`. So How to use this `inputView property` of `UITextField` ?

**Any Better Idea ?...**

Comment: There is just 2 method to do this resignFirstResponder or becomeFirstResponder by other control. what other way u find??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can not do this directly (as `inputView`). You can try this simple work around:

1) Replace your `UITextField` with `UIButton` and connect it to some selector (`buttonClicked`:). You can use `UIButtonTypeCustom` to be able to style it so it looks like text field (set layer's bordeColor, borderWidth, cornerRadius, etc..)

2) In this method `-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender` - toggle the same `UIPickerView` you would use as inputView for replaced `UITextField`. You can make in ordinary instance variable, just remember to set delegate and dataSource. Attach it to the root view (of your `UIViewController` show in popover) or even `UIWindow` and animate it in or out (toggle) depending if it is already shown or not.

3) Update button's text (by using `[button setTitle:<selected_value> forState:UIControlStateNormal]`) in `UIPickerViewDelegate` method: `pickerView:didSelect...atIndex: - you can additionally hide picker here..

Hope this would help.

Comment: As there are not many good answers here, I am accepting your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take an object in your .h file as:

```
id currentTextField;
```

Implement this `UITextField` `Delegate` Method in your .m file:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    currentTextField = textField;
}
```

- Don't forget to make the `txtField.delegate = self` for all the `UITextFields` in your file.

Now when you receive the tap on your `pickerView` Button, first add a statement on that button's click method:

```
[currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

All the best!!!

Comment: Just check my Update in the Question.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your Effort.